# Creating different cell sizes with dynamic height and full height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8

I understand how to create custom `UITableViewCell`s with a dynamic height in iOS8+.

Within our app we have some full size height cells, for error/loading states. Then we have some dynamic height cells for the actual correct content.

What is the correct way to handle a full height cell using the dynamic height approach? Previously we would use the `heightForRowAtIndex` and set the height to the be the `tableView.frame.size.height` for example.

Now we need to have some cells which would be fullsize, some which might be 200 and some which might be 240 as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setup the constraints in your full size cells to calculate to the correct height. You can either give them a constant height constraint or base it on it's content.

That way you don't have to mix absolute and dynamic heights.

Comment: But the height constraint would differ each time based on screen size and therefore table view size. Unless you mean make them programmatically and possibly do it that way...

Comment: Yes, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can set up the height constraint. It will need to be a constant height constraint with the constant set to the tableviews height.

Comment: You're right, I kind of thought that would be the only way... Think I was just looking for someone to say too :) Cheers